# How to animate backgroundTint using XML?

Tags: android

I want to animate the `backgroundTint` property(and not the `backgroundColor` property which is given everywhere else on SO)

I would like to use something similar to `StateListAnimator`s + `XML` for doing this. I tried using `propertyName="backgroundTint"`, but it didn't work.

Comment: you cannot do it in layout xml

Comment: @pskink You sure? I mean I can animate a lot of properties using XML. Why not this one? Also, if that's the case, can you tell me a way to do so? I'm open to using things other than `StateListAnimator`.

Comment: why xml? cannot you do that in java?

Comment: @pskink I can do that in Java. But: 1> XML code is usually more concise and easier to tweak. 2> I prefer keeping all visual stuff in XML. 3> The animation is to be used in a lot of screens

Comment: so you can use databinding and [custom binding adapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#custom-logic), with them you can do whatever you like